# How to update anaconda distributions and python packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a anaconda distribution installed on a OS X system.

If I look at the packages installed with anaconda navigator, I see that lots of package are upgradable. If I upgrade one of them, then I have a anaconda package in the list with the version `custum`. If I upgrade this package I came back to the previous version of the packages I have upgraded previously.

Hereafter, I followed [this](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#updating-from-older-anaconda-versions) page of the documentation.

```
--> conda update conda
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /blabla/anaconda:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    anaconda: 4.2.0-np111py35_0 --> custom-py35_0
    conda:    4.2.13-py35_0     --> 4.2.14-py35_0
    requests: 2.11.1-py35_0     --> 2.12.4-py35_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
...
[      COMPLETE      ]

--> conda update anaconda
Fetching package metadata .......
Solving package specifications: ..........

Package plan for installation in environment /blabla/anaconda:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    anaconda: custom-py35_0 --> 4.2.0-np111py35_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED due to dependency conflicts:

    conda:    4.2.14-py35_0 --> 4.2.13-py35_0
    requests: 2.12.4-py35_0 --> 2.11.1-py35_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y
...
[      COMPLETE      ]
```

As you can see, with update conda, conda and request are updated to a newer version and with update anaconda, the same packages are downgrade to an older version.

Thus my question is, given a current installation of anaconda, what should I do if I want to maintain packages and update the whole distribution ?

Answer (score 6):

This will update all packages:

```
conda update --all
```

Comment: The answer by Mike is correct in 95% of cases, but since this is a common question and the apparently obvious answer (`conda update anaconda`, which normally **you should not execute**) leads to unexpected and undesireable results (such as actually **downgrading** packages), I have provided a longer discussion of this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda

Comment: conda update conda didn't work in for me. This did. :)