# Anaconda Navigator won't launch (windows 10)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Anaconda navigator won't launch, I tried reinstalling it, that did not work either. anancondas' command prompt shows an error message. I've tried googling the answer, I guess I'm bad at it.
[this is what I see after opening anaconda prompt]
[image: 1]

p.s. I use spyder on it

Comment: I had the same problem and followed the guidance in this post:
[Update Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda)

Comment: Same issue, my solution was to reinstall anaconda on smaller path. From C:\Users\<myuser>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Anaconda3 to C:\anaconda3

Answer (score 82):

You need to run the cmd prompt from the **Scripts directory of Anaconda** where ever you have the Anaconda parent folder installed.  I happen to have in the root directory of the C drive on my Windows machine.  If you are not familiar there are two ways to do that:

**A)** Use the key combination `Win-key + R` then type `cmd` and hit return to launch the terminal window and then type: `cd C:\Anaconda\Scripts` (or whatever directory path yours is).
**B)** Navigate using windows explorer to that **Scripts** directory then type `cmd` in the address bar of that window and hit return (that will launch the terminal already set to that directory).

Next type the follow commands waiting in between for each to complete:

```
activate root
conda update -n root conda
conda update --all
```

When complete type the following and **Navigator** hopefully should launch:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I tried several other recommendations first but none worked.
Running Anaconda Navigator 1.9.6 on a Windows Server 2016 test environment.

I was previously running a newer version but downgraded due to other issues.

Comment: A year and a half later, this was the solution that worked for me

Comment: Faild for me, got:
DEBUG menuinst_win32:create(320): Shortcut cmd is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe, args are [u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\cwp.py', u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2', u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\pythonw.exe', u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\Scripts\\anaconda-navigator-script.py']
failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(507): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::pyqt-4.10.4-py27_1'.
IOError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Comment: I get a Pyside error....ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'.. still no luck...EDIT.. reinstall pyQt5... did it for me

Comment: Using VSCode with anaconda, this solution worked for me.

Comment: I was getting mad after a windows updated, Anaconda stopped working i tried everything but this worked perfectly (after uninstall and reinstall)

Comment: This worked for me, but is extremely slow. Installing `pyqt5` would have probably done the job as well

Comment: Works even after more than 3 years later, with broken installation of the new version of Anaconda. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 41):

I had the same issue, and solved it by the following commands:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
anaconda-navigator --reset
anaconda-navigator
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me after receiving an error following the top answer. I think the reset was what got it working again.

Answer (score 18):

I am not sure why but the command below worked for me.

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Of course I updated Anaconda and Navigator before running this command.

Comment: This command worked for me, too. Before running this command, the error I got said: `This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "".`

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem which was mainly due to an update to PyQt5, the following code helped me.

Run cmd.exe as admin:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

reinstall PyQt5:

```
pip uninstall PyQt5
pip install PyQt5
pip install pyqtwebengine
```

Comment: Yeah qtwebengine error popped up
ERROR: spyder 4.0.1 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13; python_version >= "3", which is not installed.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  What is very frustrating is that this kind of work is trial and error.  Hope and pray that this time work.  There must be better way than this.  If it wasn't for this answer, I probably have given up this project.

Answer (score 15):

You need to update Anaconda using:

```
conda update
```

and

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

Try these commands on anaconda prompt and then try to launch navigator from the prompt itself using following command:

```
anaconda-navigator
```

If still the problem doesn't get solved, share the anaconda prompt logs here if they have any errors.

Comment: conda update do not work, must be conda update --prefix C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Anaconda3 anaconda

Answer (score 5):

Faced the same problem. `'conda update'` does not work; It gives the error : `"CondaValueError: no package names supplied"`

On executing the following commands, I was able to launch the **Anaconda navigator**:

```
conda update -n base conda
```

`conda update anaconda-navigator`

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing same problem. Running below command from conda command prompt solved my problem

```
pip install pyqt5
```

Answer (score 5):

So none of the above answers worked for me.

I performed the following steps in order to make it work for me : 
OS : Windows 10 Home 64 Bit

Open Anaconda Prompt

```
conda remove anaconda-navigator
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

`conda install -c anaconda pywin32`  // Had to install since I got a module not found error 
                                   // with just the above two commands

And it worked for me!!

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this problem for a couple of hours (got the same error message you showed in your attachment). I knew the problem had to do with the path variable, specifically the PYTHONHOME variable.

I finally found I had set the PYTHONHOME path to the python.exe file (C:\Anaconda3\python.exe). It should be set to the Anaconda folder that contains the python.exe file (C:\Anaconda3).

After that I could run the Anaconda Navigator.

Comment: same here. I'd changed the PYTHONHOME path with an older version of python, and I forgot to change it when installing Anaconda.

Answer (score 2):

This helped to me:

```
conda install anaconda-navigator
```

Comment: Obvious, but necessary!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following @janny loco's answer first and then reset anaconda to get it to work.

Step 1:

```
activate root
conda update -n root conda
conda update --all
```

Step 2:

`anaconda-navigator --reset`

After running the update commands in step 1 and not seeing any success, I reset anaconda by running the command above based on what I found [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1764).

I am not sure if it was the combination of updating conda and reseting the navigator or just one of the two. So, please try accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Could not launch Anaconda after reinstalling. I believe this was mentioned above but followed these four steps at the command line and worked perfectly:

1. conda update conda
2. conda update anaconda-navigator
3. anaconda-navigator --reset
4. anaconda-navigator

Comment: Works better for my situation:

1. conda update conda
2. conda update --all
3. conda update anaconda-navigator
4. anaconda-navigator --reset
5. anaconda-navigator

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest conda and latest navigator will resolve this issue.

Open the Anaconda Prompt and type

- conda update conda

and

- conda update anaconda-navigator

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked doing this:

Uninstall the previous version: 
go to **C:\users\username\anaconda3** and run the **anaconda-uninstall.exe**

Install again anaconda

then run the following commands on the **anaconda pompt**:

conda create -n my_env python=2.7

conda activate my_env

start the gui app

anaconda-navigator

Answer (score 0):

I was working on my Windows 10 machine and I'm not sure which package "broke" Spyder and Anaconda Navigator, but could have been either, or, or both Kivy-1.10.1 and moviepy-0.2.3.5 which gave me problems. I installed with either pip or conda.
So of course I looked on this site to see what to do to fix.  I found how pyqt was probably the issue.  I uninstalled pyqt, kivy, and moviepy by using "pip uninstall ".  I found where/or how they were installed by "pip list" and "conda list".   After they were uninstalled I used "conda install - c anaconda pyqt" to reinstall pyqt.  After installing pyqt I launched Spyder with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the member "Python" from username>AppData>Roaming(Python).

I renamed the member to username>AppData>Roaming(PythonBackup).

Python was partially still installed on my computer so it was having trouble installing it.

When I did get it installed it wasn't working and I found the Python on a traceback it gave when I tried to run Anaconda Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything I could to launch Conda Navigator but failed. What to do now ?

I'm using Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.928]

**Step 1- Activated root**

C:\Users\LENOVO>activate root

(base) C:\Users\LENOVO>conda update -n root conda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):

defaults/noarch::sphinx-3.1.2-py_0, defaults/win-64::docutils-0.17-py38haa95532_1
defaults/noarch::sphinx-3.5.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0, defaults/win-64::docutils-0.16-py38done
All requested packages already installed.

**Step 2 - conda update -all**

(base) C:\Users\LENOVO>conda update --all

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment:
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):

defaults/noarch::sphinx-3.1.2-py_0, defaults/win-64::docutils-0.17-py38haa95532_1
defaults/noarch::sphinx-3.5.4-pyhd3eb1b0_0, defaults/win-64::docutils-0.16-py38done
Package Plan
environment location: C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3

The following packages will be downloaded:

### package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
beautifulsoup4-4.9.3       |     pyha847dfd_0          86 KB
conda-build-3.21.4         |   py38haa95532_0         552 KB

```
                                   Total:         637 KB
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

beautifulsoup4 anaconda/win-64::beautifulsoup4-4.9.1~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-pyha847dfd_0
conda-build 3.18.11-py38_1 --> 3.21.4-py38haa95532_0
python 3.8.3-he1778fa_2 --> 3.8.8-hdbf39b2_5

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages
conda-build-3.21.4 | 552 KB | ############################################################################ | 100%
beautifulsoup4-4.9.3 | 86 KB | ############################################################################ | 100%
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done

**Step 3 - tried launching anaconda navigator**

(base) C:\Users\LENOVO>anaconda-navigator

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in
from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 34, in
from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 30, in
from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 19, in
import binstar_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binstar_client'

**Step 4 - tried installing anaconda - client**

(base) C:\Users\LENOVO>conda install anaconda-client

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

All requested packages already installed.

**Step 5 - Tried relaunching but failed**
Again I tried to launch anaconda navigator (same output) -

(base) C:\Users\LENOVO>anaconda-navigator

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 10, in
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 103, in main
from anaconda_navigator.app.start import start_app
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\start.py", line 34, in
from anaconda_navigator.widgets.main_window import MainWindow
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\widgets\main_window.py", line 34, in
from anaconda_navigator.api.anaconda_api import AnacondaAPI
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\anaconda_api.py", line 30, in
from anaconda_navigator.api.client_api import ClientAPI
File "C:\Users\LENOVO\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\client_api.py", line 19, in
import binstar_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binstar_client'

Comment: If you have a question, can you post it as a new question?

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this is an old question but I encountered this problem recently and I did not find the solution among the ones mentioned. After doing `conda update --all` jupyter-notebook and the others didn't launch anymore, then I had to do `conda install anaconda-navigator = 1.10.0` because the problem could be with recent versions of anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

Install Anaconda again (without uninstalling the previous version) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, None of the answers above worked for me. Your issue can have multiple reasons, maybe .condarc might have been corrupted, you can try to delete it and restart the Anaconda navigator. When your problem occurs, even `conda install` command might not work, in such case run the below command.

```
pip3 install pyOpenSSL --upgrade
```

After running the above command, Anaconda Navigator launched.

EDIT: i got the solution from here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/12234
This problem is different but it will still work for Anaconda navigator not launching. When Anaconda navigator didn't launch, i opened prompt to launch it from prompt, there i got an error, then i tried conda install then i got the error which is mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

It works better for my situation:

```
conda update conda  
conda update --all  
conda update anaconda-navigator  
anaconda-navigator --reset  
anaconda-navigator
```