# Anaconda Crashes Every time I launch

Tags: python, crash, installation, anaconda

I just installed Anaconda to use it for python, however, whenever I try to launch the navigator it crashes straight away.

I have tried reinstalling, even opening cmd and typing "conda update conda" but all I get is 
"

Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Fierce PC\Anaconda3\python.exe "**C:\Users\Fierce PC\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" update conda'

Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Fierce PC\Anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\Fierce PC\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.cmd.exe reactivate'**

"
Please, can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: you could try [anaconda-navigator-wont-launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10/51466210#51466210)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anaconda Navigator won't launch (windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

You have to go into start and use the anaconda (prompt) in your start menu.

Comment: Hello @FLokiiSon, welcome to SO. Excessive greetings, salutations, thanks giving are not helping to solve the problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351589/13736525