# How to retrieve and run anaconda navigator after deleting anaconda propmt

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Today when I was using **jupyter notebook** using anaconda navigator in my windows 10 machine but suddenly my screen became blue and loading screen appeared saying that some sort of error occurred then my computer restarted.

After restarting, my anaconda navigator got lost and anaconda prompt appeared in the start menu.I clicked but it said `anaconda 3 system cannot find the path specified`.

I tried reinstalling anaconda several times but nothing changed. Then reinstalled python still no change. I thought may be anaconda prompt needs to be deleted, so I deleted it. Now nothing appears on the start menu which I can use to start anaconda navigator no matter how many times I reinstall it.

I even tried to reinstall jupyter using PIP3 but installation fails. I really don't know how I am going to run `.ipybn` files.

Comment: Can you tell us what operating system you're using?

Comment: My operating system is windows 10.

Comment: Can you try the instructions in the top answer here and let me know what if any errors you get? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10

Comment: I checked the link which you sent me. But There are so many scripts folder in my PC I don't know which one I should use.May be if I knew what the scripts folder contains then I could've understood better. I tried using this one C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\pkgs\anaconda-client-1.7.2-py37_0 but it didn't work. I was able to follow only the first suggestion.