# Anaconda navigator shows initializing and closes immediately

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

[image]

[image]

I have installed anaconda3 on my laptop but every time I try to launch anaconda navigator from windows start menu or anaconda prompt or even command prompt, anaconda navigator would show initializing and then immediately stops. I have attached some pictures of it for reference. I have tried running lots of commands in command prompt and anaconda prompt searching from the internet in order to fix this issue but none of them worked, I used commands like conda update conda, conda update anaconda-navigator, conda update navigator-updater, conda update --all, conda remove anaconda-navigator and then conda install anaconda-navigator, anaconda-navigator --reset and tried launching anaconda-navigator again and many more searching from the internet.

Any help is really appreciated anything if that worked for you might work for me as well so please help me. I'm stuck in my projects.

Thank you
Deepankar Pradhan

Comment: Have you tried to remove and uninstall it fully and then install it again. It may have some installation issues.

Comment: I have tried that before as well but that didn't help me.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10) you may find solution. Its already answered.

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work for me. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 2):

You may try one of the following:

1. Delete the `.condarc` file in the `users` folder and restart Navigator.
2. Delete the `.continuum` file and restart Navigator.
3. On conda prompt:

   ```
   conda update conda
   conda update anaconda-navigator
   conda update navigator-updater
   anaconda-navigator --reset
   ```

   Restart Navigator