# anaconda-navigator doesn't get past the initializing screen (doesn't give any errors either) (Win10)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

> I have wiped my Windows installation since posting this. So, this post can be considered closed. But I never could solve this.

#### Problem

After freshly installing `Anaconda3 2020.11 64-bit version` on my Win10 64-bit machine, Anaconda Navigator doesn't get past the initializing splash screen. It closes immediately with no residual processes seen in task manager.

I am not able to pinpoint the issue since I am not getting any kind of error code. It simply just doesn't open. Kindly help me resolve it :)

#### Solutions Already Tried

- Uninstalled Python 3.9.4 I had previously installed.
- Already tried uninstalling and reinstalling three times (also deleted residual files and folders before attempting reinstallation.)
- All packages are up-to-date including `conda`, `pyqt`, and `anaconda-naviagtor`.
- Deleting the `.continuum` folder as mentioned in the official [troubleshooting guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/troubleshooting/) didn't help.
- Tried adding the Anaconda installation folder to the path (as read somewhere). Didn't help.
- Tried altering configurations during installation.
- Resetting `anaconda-navigator` settings or uninstalling and reinstalling it make no difference.
- Tried downgrading `anaconda-navigator` to `V1.10.0` as discussed in one of the linked GitHub issues. Didn't work.
- Also tried installing `Miniconda` and using `conda-forge` channel.

#### Some Observations

- Anaconda prompt seems to work fine.
- Running `anaconda-navigator` from Command Prompt doesn't show any errors. It launches the initializing screen and after the screen closes, it then exits to the new line (to run new command).
- After a fresh install, if only `conda` and `anaconda-navigator` are updated, navigator opens for 2-3 seconds. So maybe it's a problem with one of the packages installed.

#### Possible Cause

- I had newer version of Python already installed in my system that time.

#### Related Issues reported on Anaconda's GitHub Page:

- [#12390](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12390)
- [#12287](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12287)
- [#12381](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12381)
- [#12325](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12325)
- [#12318](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/12318)
- [#10201](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10201)

#### Related StackOverflow Question:

[Anaconda navigator shows initializing and closes immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448579/anaconda-navigator-shows-initializing-and-closes-immediately)

#### Screenshots

[image: conda prompt]

Comment: Navigator still isn't working.

Comment: What error do you get when "anaconda-navigator" opening with admin access?

Comment: @code-freeze thanks for trying to help out. But I have wiped my Windows installation since then. Can't really provide any information now :)