# Anaconda Import error, circular import error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I'm trying to use anaconda to setup an environment for jupyter notebook. It's not going well... I've got everything working without anaconda (just on the normal windows terminal). On Anaconda terminal however, whenever I try to install jupyter notebook it gives me an import error (could be circular issue it says). I also cannot open anaconda navigator through either the app or command prompt. I have followed documentation and this [video](https://anaconda.cloud/tutorials/getting-started-with-anaconda-individual-edition?source=win_installer). Please any help would be greatly appreciated, I am going to try uninstalling anaconda and then seeing if that gets me any results...

Comment: Can you show us the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Its all pathing stuff, not sure its great for sharing! I imagine that theres something incredibly wrong with the download so I'm gonna uninstall and reinstall everything (including python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10 This appears to have fixed it...

Answer (score 1):

What is the library's name are you trying to import? I am guessing 'jupyter'

Checking your local filenames might be useful. If any files in your project involve the word that is in the import statement, that could prevent the actual jupyter library being imported.

I had the same problem, tried to import numpy and got a similar error. Turns out that I had a file called 'numpy.py' in my project directory. I renamed it and solved the problem.

Comment: qiskit & juptyer-notebook, everything works from command line, but nothing works from anaconda or python terminal

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset pyzmq by doing the following:

```
pip uninstall pyzmq
pip install pyzmq
```