# Anaconda Navigator won't launch (windows 11)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I can't open Anaconda Navigator and Spyder from the drop down list (see image). No error appears.
No issue when I open Spyder and Navigator from Anaconda Prompt (CLI).
Digging into the code I see that the drop down shortcut is running `C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\cwp.py C:\ProgramData\anaconda3 C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py`
In `cwp.py` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\cwp.py", line 10, in <module>
    from menuinst._legacy.knownfolders import FOLDERID, get_folder_path
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'menuinst._legacy.knownfolders'
```

I followed the instructions in [Anaconda Navigator won't launch (windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10)
nothing helped.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear to me, what you are asking.  Is your issue attempting to open anaconda or spyder directly from a cli prompt or is it you can't open Navigator from the drop down list?

Comment: I can't open Navigator from the drop down list

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by modify "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\cwp.py" line 10
from

```
from menuinst._legacy.knownfolders import FOLDERID, get_folder_path
```

into

```
from menuinst.knownfolders import FOLDERID, get_folder_path
```