# Problem with heroku deploy due to pip freeze including all anaconda packages

Tags: python, heroku, anaconda

After following the Heroku [Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) guide, I decide to have a go at deploying my own project, however I have run into the following problems.

I am using **Pycharm** and **Anaconda**. Post creating a simple application using `pandas` I do the following in the root of the project:

```
pip freeze --local > requirements.txt
```

I then commit `requirements.txt` and attempt deploying the app.

```
git push heroku master
```

### Error

```
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting alabaster==0.7.10 (from -r /tmp/build_ee6cf004d0fea807fae99f551ec45276/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/c3/9b7dcd8548cf2c00531763ba154e524af575e8f36701bacfe5bcadc67440/alabaster-0.7.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from -r /tmp/build_ee6cf004d0fea807fae99f551ec45276/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from -r /tmp/build_ee6cf004d0fea807fae99f551ec45276/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
remote:        No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.6.14 (from -r /tmp/build_ee6cf004d0fea807fae99f551ec45276/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fish-finger-23765.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fish-finger-23765.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fish-finger-23765.git'
```

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304291/heroku-upload-could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-anaconda) it seem the work around is to manually create `requirements.txt`, which in my case entails adding `pandas==0.23.0`, however this seems like a hack - how do you successfully create a `requirements.txt` which you can successfully deploy to **Heroku**?

Comment: Have you check that you are deploying for the right Python version? These kind of errors heppen when you are using Python 2 instead of 3.

Comment: @KlausD. how would I confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

Well.... according to PyPi the highest version is 1.2.2 which would be problematic.

I see the version is 1.6.14 on the github repository. You can update your requirements file to install the package directly from GitHub.

Comment: Previously I have attempted to remove the offending packages but it quickly descends into a game of whack a mole.