# Heroku fails to bundle python-javabridge (javahome not found)

Tags: python, heroku, java-bridge-method

I am trying to deploy my first Plotly Dash app (written in Python) to Heroku. I am having trouble with bundling up all the packages to compile the app, currently with Python-javabridge.

When I try to deploy my app, **even after deleting python-javabridge from the `requirements.txt`**, it still tries to bundle it, giving me the following error:

```
remote:        Collecting jeepney>=0.4.2; sys_platform == "linux"
remote:          Downloading jeepney-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
remote:        Collecting importlib-resources; python_version < "3.7"
remote:          Downloading importlib_resources-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-javabridge==4.0.0
remote:          Downloading python-javabridge-4.0.0.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qllzoihk/python-javabridge/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qllzoihk/python-javabridge/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-xeh4coov
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qllzoihk/python-javabridge/
remote:            Complete output (11 lines):
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-qllzoihk/python-javabridge/setup.py", line 412, in <module>
remote:                ext_modules=ext_modules(),
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-qllzoihk/python-javabridge/setup.py", line 96, in ext_modules
remote:                java_home = find_javahome()
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-qllzoihk/python-javabridge/javabridge/locate.py", line 133,
in find_javahome
remote:                java_bin = get_out(["bash", "-c", "type -p java"])
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-install-qllzoihk/python-javabridge/javabridge/locate.py", line 130,
in get_out
remote:                raise Exception("Error finding javahome on linux: %s" % cmd)
remote:            Exception: Error finding javahome on linux: ['bash', '-c', 'type -p java']
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

**What I have done:**

Just running `pip install javabridge` works perfectly, no problems.

I added `JAVA_HOME` to my system variables and to path, didn't help. Writing `javac` or `java --version` on the cmd outputs the version as expected.

I use Windows 10, Python 3.7, Anaconda3, Spyder terminal to run the commands.

Comment: You should explain more detailed what you are doing there and especially how Heroku is involved.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added some more info, apologies for the lack of clarity :)

Comment: Heroku *is* running on Linux. Those logs are from Heroku's servers (notice the "remote:"). You push your code to Heroku, and it will try to install your app's dependencies on its servers.

Comment: Ah thank, this is too new to me. I will change the title so it is not misleading. I'll look for the problem in java_home then. I'm confused because pip install javabridge works fine, the java_home seems to be correctly set according to everything I read about it online. :(

Comment: Heruko runs on Linux and will build your application in Linux. And for that it can't use your locally installed software like Java. To debug why the removed dependency is still installed check `git status` and post the requirements.

Comment: If pip install javabridge works fine *locally*, on your machine, it does not mean it will also work on Heroku. So it's not just *your* environment's JAVA_HOME you need to fix, but also how Heroku can install that same package on its own environment (which is totally separate from your Windows machine).

Comment: Thank you so much, that's super insightful. If it happens with a critical package, how would I troubleshoot a Linux problem from my Windows machine?

Comment: @KlausD. git status just shows there are no changes, but running git show master:requirements.txt does show the edited dependencies (with the deleted packages, including python-javabridge) .. so no idea what is making it install it anyway..

Comment: @Isquare1 you are deploying aap with git or you are using docker

Comment: it is with git, this seems to be the way heroku usually does it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Java from a Python application on Heroku you'll need to use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app). Note that

> The buildpack for the **primary** language of your app should always be the **last** buildpack in the list. This ensures that defaults for that primary language are applied instead of those for another language, and allows Heroku to correctly detect the primary language of your app.

So in this case, do something like

```
PS C:\> heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
PS C:\> heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/jvm
```

If you run `heroku buildpacks` you should now see [the JVM buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common) listed first and the Python buildpack listed second. Note that we are using `heroku/jvm` here, not `heroku/java`, since you aren't building a Java application.

After doing this you'll need to redeploy your application. If you have changes to make, go ahead and make them, then commit, and push.

Note that your application might need to use the Java bridge even if you aren't directly depending on it in your `requirements.txt`, e.g. if one of your dependencies depends on it.

Comment: Thank you loads for taking the time to help me out with this, I have some more reading to do, the links you provided were very useful! I set up the buildpacks and although now java_home is located, now I get a ModuleNotFoundError: 'No module named 'numpy'  from the python-javabridge setup.py file...it's the first time I've had this error

Comment: PS Looks like it has to do with heroku/git running the setup.py file before downloading numpy so solving it seems to involve delving into some setuptools that I'm not familiar with. But I select your answer as the correct one, as it solved the java_home problem that I was stuck on for days, thank you for that :)

Comment: Weird. Is `javabridge` in your `requirements.txt`? I know you said you took it out, but did you put it back in? If not, how are you installing it? What about `numpy`?

Comment: I took it out for good, but it still tries to install it anyway, together with a few other packages.. You mentioned it could be that they are requirements for some of the dependencies? Numpy is installed and is in the requirements.txt.I have pip installed javabridge and numpy on my local PC and it is all fine. It seems it is a common problem with deploying apps but I am not that proficient to be changing the setuptools of javabridge myself..  https://forum.predix.io/questions/30529/python-setuppy-cant-import-module-even-though-that.html

Comment: Are you entirely sure that you have committed your updated `requirements.txt` file, and included that commit when you push to Heroku? Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?

Comment: Yes, I even checked the requirements.txt as committed to git (with git:show) and it is indeed the updated requirments.txt. I suspect the java wrapper is just a requirement for all Dash apps, because entering pip check in the given env does not show any of the packages to have javabridge as a dependency. I don't have a Pipfile, I will look into it, thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Isquare1, to clarify, you probably should _not_ have a `Pipfile`. That's an alternative to `requirements.txt`, and it takes precedence on Heroku. I was just trying to see if Heroku might be using a different set of dependencies. Use either (a) `requirements.txt` or (b) `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, not both.