# What is the difference between conda 'base' and 'root' enviroments?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have recently been pulling my hair out trying to organize my conda environments. I ended up reinstalling miniconda and I'm in a good spot.

My question is this, when I run `conda env list` I get:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/rheft/miniconda3
sonny36                  /Users/rheft/miniconda3/envs/sonny36
```

I would expect "root" to be included here. Further more when I look at my conda environments from inside jupyter notebooks there are 3 environments listed.

```
root         -- /Users/rheft/miniconda3
miniconda3   -- /Users/rheft/miniconda3
sonny36      -- /Users/rheft/miniconda3/envs/sonny36
```

My question is why is it that `root` doesn't show when I run `conda env list`?  Although everything works correctly, I would like to remove the duplicated environment if possible, any suggestions?

Many thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `jupyter kernelspec list`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`root` is the old (pre-conda 4.4) name for the main environment; after conda 4.4, it was renamed to be `base`. Most likely the reason you have a Jupyter environment named `root` is because you have a kernel installed with that name in it.

Comment: As per your comment above. Running `jupyter kernelspec list` returns 3 availble kernels: `python3`, `sonny`, `sonny36`. Im not sure where the "python3" came from, but "sonny" was an old conda enviroment I had before I nuked the entire thing to start over... I can research myself, but do you know of any easy way to remove these? For cleanliness sake. Thanks for the answer as well!