# Anaconda python ver5.3 hangs at update forever

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-3.7

I just installed anaconda ver5.3 which uses python v3.7

I ran the command;

```
conda update anaconda
```

The command hangs there forever. There is no error message. No hint what is wrong. Has anyone encountered similar problems? How did you solve it?

I am using Windows 10 and was previously using anaconda ver5.2 which uses python v3.6.

Comment: What is your OS? What is the current version of anaconda?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and anaconda ver5.2 which uses python v3.6.

Comment: Do you have two anaconda environments? Are you installing v5.3 alongside any previous versions?

Comment: I have tried both. Having 2 anaconda environments (v5.3 and v5.2) and 1 anaconda environment (v5.3). I encounter the same problem in both cases.

Comment: see this link for some hints https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6406

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running

```
conda update anaconda --verbose
```

to get some insight. Adding `--verbose` multiple times increases logging to INFO, DEBUG and then TRACE level.

https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-update.html

Answer (score 5):

I think this could solve your problem to update anaconda, and yes it seems like a fairly common issue:

1) install the latest miniconda3 from [here](https://conda.io/miniconda.html)

2) make sure you run anaconda prompt as admin

3) update to latest version of conda

`conda update conda`

4) install anaconda

`conda install anaconda`

5) install navigator

`conda install anaconda-navigator`

6) verify conda is installed and check package number

`conda info`

View packages you installed in anaconda docs page [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs)

Comment: This answer put me on the right track, so thank you for that, but you may want to add the piece of advice of rebooting windows before trying the different step, or the admin shell may hang too.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the feedback. At what point did you experience this? I haven't actually run into that problem before so this is helpful info!

Comment: Somewhere around "Solving environment" if I remember correctly... I'm sorry I can't be more specific. Anyway, I am sure pretty much any Windows user has experienced locked files that will stay locked no matter what until a reboot makes them accessible again, right? :)  Not incredibly surprising that some of that happens under the hood and makes the conda scripts hang.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem on Windows 10.

This problem has been fixed with the latest anaconda release ver5.3.1. You are using ver5.3. Please use the latest version. It should solve your problem.