# Anaconda: When I upgrade Jupyter it gives me version 4.4.0 when I know a stable release beyond version 5.x exists

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I check my version Jupyter and it says 4.4.0, then I try to update with `conda update jupyter` and it tells me I already have the latest version.  However, there is a version 5.x listed on the Jupyter site.  I tried updating conda itself with `conda update conda` and again it reports that I already have the latest.

I looked at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197778/3047729 and it talked about setting up separate environments, but I'm unsure whether that solution is the best one for this problem.  If it is, would the appropriate command be `conda create -n myspecialenv -c notebook=5.7.4`?  Will all other packages still be available and in their "normal" version, even after updating in the future?  And however you specify the most recent version, wouldn't it just be better just do the same thing to update the "global" version of Jupyter rather than create a separate environment for the up-to-date one?

The referenced link in that answer is dead, but I think this is the current link that would hold equivalent information: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#deactivating-an-environment

Comment: Which command did you use to find out the version? Include the output of this command in your question: `jupyter notebook --version`

Comment: @smac89 Huh, that comes out 5.7.4, I had no idea `jupyter notebook` was it's own separate thing.

Comment: I believe the version you are seeing is for jupyter-core and 4.4.0 is the [latest](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/releases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `jupyter --version`, it gives you the version for `jupyter_core` which is just one of the components that make up jupyter.

In most cases, one is mostly interested in the jupyter notebook version, in which case, the version can be realized by running `jupyter notebook --version`.