# Is updating Anaconda.Navigator risky?

Tags: python, anaconda

At startup Anaconda.Navigator asks *"Do you wish to update to Anaconda Version [some version number]"*, it also says *"strongly recommended"*.

On the other hand, this thread indicates, updating of things related to Anaconda can be a very intricate and complex task, and I might need to be careful not to break anything:
[How do I update Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda)

So the question is, if I'm lazy and click *Yes* in the update dialog of Anaconda.Navigator, what am I actually updating? Do I risk breaking any of the packages or applications managed within the Anaconda.Navigator?

Answer (score 0):

So this is cleary an opinionated question.

If you have a **clean Anaconda installation** there is little risk related with updating the packages since this is the very purpose of the Anaconda distribution.

However,

- if you didn't read the docs and during installation still deviated from the default settings ("hey, in the end it's just Python"),
- if you don't know the difference between `conda update --all` and `conda update anaconda`,
- if you prefer the Navigator over the conda cli:

**Yes**, you are facing a higher risk to end up with an installation that you actually didn't want.

Comment: I might have rephrased it to the sentence in the end of my post:  "what am I actually updating?" Which "docs" are you referring to? In my end the problem is that I don't have to full picture of the hierarchy between python/conda/anaconda and all the packages and libraries and my OS. So it's not clear exactly where to look for the right information when updating things to know if I might break things.