# How to update all the packages within an environment using the standalone version of Spyder version 5 and mini conda?

Tags: python, conda, spyder

I have downloaded and installed the standalone version of Spyder version 5 and mini conda.

With the help of the community I have now been able to create new environments.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to update all the packages within an environment using the standalone version of Spyder version 5 and mini conda?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if you installed Anaconda or Miniconda or what IDE (Spyder, VSCode) you are using. The command you are looking for is

```
conda update -n <myenv> --all
```

where `<myenv>` is the name of your environment. Note that you have to issue that command in your shell, preferably the **Anaconda prompt** or **cmd** on Windows.

Read more in the docs:
https://www.anaconda.com/blog/keeping-anaconda-date

Comment: Amusing that those "docs" are just a verbatim reproduction of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197778/570918)

Comment: The SO respondent previously worked at Anaconda.