# Anaconda3 update through command prompt on windows 10 giving 'executing transaction' for too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, anaconda3

I started to update my anaconda3 2022 version on windows 10 by running command prompt as administrator.

```
**conda update conda**
```

did well. (identify, verify & execute transactions done smoothly).
However, when I go to
`**conda update anaconda**`,

the executing transactions step was on for almost two hours, but still to no avail. Finally I ended the operation and restarted my laptop.
Trying to uninstall and reinstall same anaconda version through locally saved anaconda setup and will then try to update once again.
Any advice on how I must ensure the correct updates?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update Anaconda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda)

Answer (score 0):

The base Anaconda installation is huge and so checking and resolving all of the dependencies takes a long time.  I doubt you really need to update Conda, especially on a fresh install.  It it likely only a few patch versions behind.  Instead, you can turn off the message about upgrading to the newest version using:

```
conda config --set notify_outdated_conda false
```

Comment: Was reading another thread elsewhere and since the anaconda 2022 version is configured for python3.9, with python 3.10 being my version for balance IDEs like VS code, I am trying to make the same avaialble for jupyter etc through anaconda. trying to update the anaconda setup for the same. the executing transaction is still on after my reinstallation of anaconda.. have also made some changes. if it works well, will share the results here.
thanks for the response though.