# ResolvedPackNotFound python = 3.1 when install any package

Tags: python, installation, streamlit

I'm running Python 3.10.4 and am unable to install just about package I was hoping to use, such as Streamlit, Oracle_CX, etc... does anyone have experience overcoming the ResolvePackageNotFound: - python 3.1 message? I was only able to successfully install plotly, seaborn, and a few other packages.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with `pip` - [pip streamlit](https://pypi.org/project/streamlit/) .

`streamlit` have hardcore C dependencies..Even `streamlit` community suggets to install package with `pip`...Conda is best for installing like git or openjdk, c++ dependencies....Conda fails 70 - 80% of times while installing the libraries which are built on hardcore C dependencies

```
pip install streamlit
```

Comment: now I get: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement streamlit (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for streamlit
WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

Comment: Try installing in base environmnet...Just to check...Like I mean before activating `virtual environmnet`

Comment: same message unfortunately

Comment: Clear cache & restart laptop/once...if Same issue then create a new virtual environmnet try intsalling same....If same try updating `conda`...Like see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda