# import pandas error: cannot import name 'raises_chained_assignment_error' from 'pandas._testing.contexts'

Tags: pandas, pip, conda

Pandas version: 2.0.3
Python 3.11.4
Numpy 1.24.3

I tried updating pandas to 2.2.0 using pip in the vscode terminal.

I had originally set up the environment using anaconda a long time ago.

Could the problem be because of the different package managers? How do i fix it?

Comment: Why update via pip? Anything preventing you from using conda? Why suddenly update pandas selectively and not the rest? conda can do that for you while caring for module compatibilities. Have you checked the [conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) as well as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45197777/12846804)